# Duplicated http request using HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, http

I have a scenario where an `HttpListener` listens for http requests. I created a thread where is called `Request` method of `HttpListenerContext`:

```
while (true)
{
    var ctx = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest req = ctx.Request;
    ...
    ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    ctx.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";
    ctx.Response.Close();
}
```

The problem here is that even if i send only one request (for example by telnet) sometimes i see a lot of requests. The listener prefix is `http://localhost:9999`. The strange thing is that printing remote endpoint of the request i see two or more different end points for each request. Any ideas?